# Matrices and Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am having trouble with a certain question.

We denote $D$ the differentiation operator and $T:V \rightarrow V$ a linear transformation which maps p(x) onto xp'(x)

Let W be the image of V under TD such that TD=T[D(p(x))]. Find the bases for V and for W relative to which the matrix of TD is in diagonal form.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is $V$? Doesn't $T$ *only multiplies* with $x$, and thus $xp'$ is just $TD(p)$ (for polynomial $p$)?

Comment: V is the linear space of all real polynomials of degree $\leq 3$ (sorry about that)

Comment: Please edit that into the question --- people shouldn't need to read the comments to understand the question.

Comment: So, then $TD(p)=xp''$, right?

Comment: Yes, TD(p)=xp".

Comment: The image of $V$ under $TD$ is two-dimensional, so the matrix isn't square.

Comment: Yes, that's why $W$ is introduced.

Comment: @Berci, $W$ is introduced as the image of $V$, and that image is 2-dimensional.

Comment: @Gerry: Yes. In my reading your question rather concerns on '*diagonal form*' of a nonsquare matrix..

Comment: The question is asked as a problem following another one, so I wasn't sure if the basis of V was important to mention

Comment: We all know the standard basis of $V$ (once $V$ is clear), but thanks... Btw, how do you mean '*diagonal form*' of a nonsquare matrix?

Comment: Ok. Just wanted to make sure

Comment: I don't know.. That is what is written in my book.

Comment: Generally the term "diagonal matrix" implies that the matrix is square.  This leads me to believe that they want the matrix of $TD$ as a map into $V$, not into $W$.  Does the question explicitly mention $W$ or is that your addition?

Comment: Yes it is the composition

Comment: No it is explicitly mentioned in the problem

Comment: I think we can think of $D$ as $V\to V$ too, only that it kills the fourth coordinate, and we're fine.

Comment: My bad. Misread. $TD=xp''$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the matrix you get isn't square I'm going to assume that "diagonal form" means you want all nonzero entries in the matrix to be on the diagonal that extends from the upper left corner.  This is not a diagonal matrix though... so I think this is a strangely worded question.

**Hint:** $TD$ lowers degree's by $1$ so $W$ is going to be polynomials of degree $\leq 2$.  The standard basis for $V$ is $\{1, x, x^2, x^3\}$ and the standard basis for $W$ is $\{1, x, x^2\}$.  These bases will work, just not in that order.

Keep the basis for $W$ in the order that it's in and try changing the order of the basis for $V$ to make the matrix diagonal.

Comment: We can work with a row of zeroes as DonAntonio does.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}TD(1)&=&0&=0\cdot 1+0\cdot x+0\cdot x^2+0\cdot x^3\\
TD(x)&=T(1)=&0&=0\cdot 1+0\cdot x+0\cdot x^2+0\cdot x^3\\
TD(x^2)&=T(2x)=&2x&=0\cdot 1+2\cdot x+0\cdot x^2+0\cdot x^3\\
TD(x^3)&=T(3x^2)=&6x^2&=0\cdot 1+0\cdot x+6\cdot x^2+0\cdot x^3\end{align*}$$

Thus, wrt the given basis, the matrix corresponding to $\,TD\,$ is

$$A:=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&0\\0&0&2&0\\0&0&0&6\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\Longrightarrow p_A(t):=\det(tI-A)=\begin{vmatrix}t&0&0&0\\0&t&-2&0\\0&0&t&-6\\0&0&0&t\end{vmatrix}=t^4$$

So the matrix is nilpotent but certainly not diagonalizable as the only nilpotent diagonalizable matrix is the zero matrix (why? Check the minimal polynomial....)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the concept of determinant. We still haven't seen this

Comment: I can't think right now from the top of my head of any other method but "guessing" basis that gives a diagonal form, which seems a ridiculous method indeed. How do you "find" then the diagonal form, in case it exists, of a matrix?!

Comment: @DonAntonio I'm trying to help in the chat. One might try and model two bases $B_1,B_2$ with a diagonal matrix and show they can't exist.

Comment: I really have no the slightest, palest idea how to do that choosing out of $\,\aleph_0\,$ options to choose those bases, @PeterTamaroff

Comment: Translating your idea to simplest words, you can say the following: "Saying the matrix is diagonalizable means there exist two basis such that $|TD|_{B_1B_2}$ is diagonal which means there exists a matrix $U$ (a matrix to change of basis) such that, if $M$ is your canonical matrix, $UMU^{-1}=D$ where $D$ is diagonal, not identically zero. But $M$ is nilpotent, which means $U$ can't exist."

Comment: Well, of course: in *this* particular case, but in general I don't think it is reasonably doable, and anyway: if the OP hasn't yet studied determinants, eigenvalues and etc., perhaps he hasn't yet studied nilpotent transformations/matrices and/or how to distinguish them...

Answer (score 0):

The matrix of $TD=p\mapsto xp''$ in the standard basis $(1,x,x^2,x^3)$ is: (The image of $i^\text{th}$ basis element is written in the $i^\text{th}$ column -- unless I miscalculated:)
$$[TD]=\pmatrix{0&0&0&0\\0&0&2&0\\0&0&0&6\\0&0&0&0}$$
Now find the eigenvectors for this. (It is seen that $e_1$ and $e_2$ are already  eigenvectors with eigenvalue $0$.)

Comment: I haven't seen eigenvectors still

Comment: I was mislead by P.Tamaroff's comment. I have edited the matrix. Hmm.. haven't seen eigenvectors? ..

Comment: @Berci Sorry. I corrected it later on. Will delte the misleading comment.

Comment: No problem. You convinced me for a minute.. :)